# Multitenant using Spring LDAP

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ldap, multi-tenant

I am developing Spring Based multitenant application.  I was refering to an article @ http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-saas/index.html

It shows how to implement Multitenant application using Spring Security + LDAP. But it seems that article is written in 2008 and is applicable to Spring Security 2.0.1. whereas I am using latest version of Spring Security (3.1.3).

In latest Version, I am not able to locate `SpringSecurityContextSource` class.

Any suggestion on how to achieve same functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just removed references of SpringSecurityContextSource. Still application is working as expected.